# why is the maximum position of control in a form in vb.net is 32767? (when auto scroll property of the form is enabled)

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to position a control in form at (100,40000), but when the form is running the position is at (100,32767). why is it so?

Comment: We need *a lot more* informations about that

Comment: You should include the relevant code in your question. Also, is this winforms? I'd imagine position is a short since very rarely is a monitor's height greater than 32k pixels

Comment: 32767 is the maximum value of a short, which seems to be used for the position, so I think there is nothing you can do about that,

Comment: A screen with 40k pixels in one direction? Seriously?

Comment: textBox1.Location = New Point(100,40000). But the point takes int32 type as input arguments.

Comment: @HimBromBeere - The only thing I could think of is the op is trying to code a display for [times square](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c0/1_times_square_night_2013.jpg). But I doubt even these have that high of a res

Comment: See, @HimBromBeere this is a workshop given to me to find the explanation, not any practical scenario.

Answer (score 0):

From the source code for [System.Windows.Forms Location](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,fe6221f0995f8f41):

```
    SRCategory(SR.CatLayout),
    Localizable(true),
    SRDescription(SR.ControlLocationDescr)
    ]
    public Point Location {
        get {
            return new Point(x, y);
        }
        set {
            SetBounds(value.X, value.Y, width, height, BoundsSpecified.Location);
        }
    }
```

As you can see, it calls a method `SetBounds` which will restrict values entered.

Note: even though this is c# im sure that the answer is the same for vb.net

Source for [`SetBounds`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,33d7e3e95057a74d)